# What software for wireless redirect to TOU page?

Tags: proxy, redirect, wifi

What software is typically used to redirect users on a public WAP to a TOU page?

For example, at McDonald's if you jump on their free wireless, you cannot SSH until first attempting to use a browser, which is redirected to a corporate TOU page that you must agree to before you get a fully-capable connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a captive portal.

Most higher-end commercial wireless controllers can do such a thing.

If you're looking to implement such a thing, [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org) does it. We've implemented exactly that for customers of ours.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in your wireless router without doing a whole captive portal.  For example, if you can run an appropriate [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com) on your router, you can set up [NoCatSplash](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/NoCatSplash) to force a user to log in and agree to a terms of service page.  Typically you want to pick a router with more than 4MB of flash, so you can install one of the larger firmware images that supports more features like this.